# How do I do basic customization of a custom Chromecast Receiver app? Like setting the background image while loading?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, custom-receiver

I have a custom Chromecast receiver app with [the most basic code](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/basic):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <cast-media-player></cast-media-player>
  <script>
    cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works but it's very ugly. When you hit cast the app brings up "MyCustomReceiver" (the name of my receiver) while it loads. I'd prefer to have a splash screen or a thumbnail for the content being loaded. Or heck even just delete the gross "MyCustomReceiver" text.

I looked at the [Customize UI docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui)

It says you can hook into keywords like `--playback-logo-image` to customize the UI.

I try this:

```
body {
  --playback-logo-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kV5GW0A.jpg');
}
```

Nothing happens. I expected it to show up as the logo as shown further down in the page.

I try setting it for `--buffering-image`. Also no luck.

```
body {
  --buffering-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kV5GW0A.jpg');
}
```

How am I supposed to customize this?

Answer (score 1):

Basic customization can be done with CSS itself. The SDK (V3) has its own CSS variables for this.

```
 <style>

 body {
      --watermark-size: 120px;
      --watermark-image: url("your-img-location/url");
      --splash-image:url("your-img-location/url");
      --logo-image:url("your-img-location/url");
      --progress-color: #ffd200;
 }

 </style>
```

Add this  tag on receiver HTML File

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar difficulties figuring out what each styling keyword does, you may want to reference the [styled media receiver docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver).

I think `--logo-image` will replace the default receiver text.